# Regular Expression to divide 5.55FIX as 5.55 and FIX

Tags: regex

I need to parse a String having entry 5.55FIX, 5.55 Variable, 5.55Float. I need to extract the decimal value and the string as separate. please suggest?

Comment: What language will be interpreting this regex?  Regex definitions differ between languages, such as JavaScript using the older PERL regex and XML using a newer regex that is more definitive using fewer characters.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need a regular expression? If your entire string is "[somenumber]FIX" you could just chop off the last three characters.

Comment: But Joren the Decimal Digit might have precision of 3 or 4 digit like 56.785

Comment: So you can just find the index of the first letter and do a substring from 0 to that index, and another substring from that index to the end of the original string. Regexes are pretty hard to understand, so if there is a simple solution like this it's probably better to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where you're going to use the regex, one of this will surely do the job.
Group 1 will contain the number, group 2 will contain the string. Of course this is assuming the string never begins with a number and without a whitespace between the actual number (in which case it couldn't even be told apart by a human unless he knows either the value of the number or that of the string in advance).

```
(\d+\.\d+)\W*(\w+)
(\d+\.\d+)\p{Z}*(\w+)
```

As suggested by Drew Noakes, if you only care about the decimal part you may also use one of these:

```
\d+(\.\d+)\W*(\w+)
\d+(\.\d+)\p{Z}*(\w+)
```

As suggested by David Andres, you can improve the expressions by adding ^ at the beginning and $ at the end if you're going to use the regex on strings made up only in the way you've stated in your post. This means that with those two characters, "5.55FIX" will match but "Value: 5.55FIX" will not.

Comment: Unless you expect to match numbers of the format `55.` then the regex could be enhanced so that the number formatting portion changes from `\d+\.\d+` to `\d+(\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to fit your exact questions would be...

```
^(5\.55)(FIX)$
```

Comment: You answer only the title... Although the body is a bit confusing as well.